# How to deploy Vue.js application on IIS over Virtual Directory?

Tags: iis, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I need to deploy a Vue.js application on IIS over a virtual directory, but when I deploy it I have to change my routes to include the virtual directory name.

My original routes is like that:

```
export const routes = [
    { path: '', component: Default, props: true },
    { path: '/Path', component: Path, props: true },
    { path: '/Path/:IdPath', component: PathForm, props: true }
];
```

But to work, I had to change my routes to include the virtual directory name, like that:

```
export const routes = [
    { path: '/VirtualDirectory', component: Default, props: true },
    { path: '/VirtualDirectory/Path', component: Path, props: true },
    { path: '/VirtualDirectory/Path/:IdPath', component: PathForm, props: true }
];
```

And this is a problem, because if I need to change my server or my virtual directory I'll have to re-deploy my Vue.js application to include the new virtual directory name.

Are there a way to make this dinamic?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to configure the *publicPath*, by default this is set to "/", e.g. if you look in your generated index.html you will see:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script></body>
```

Notice the "/app.js" above.

You can configure this by adding a *vue.config.js* file to the root of your project and adding a *publicPath* setting:

```
module.exports = {
   publicPath: '/my-virtual-directory'
}
```

See the official Vue documentation https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack-cli, one thing you can do is to give your directory (mostly vuejs root dir) an `alias`. inside your `webpack.config.js` So, in this following example:

```
alias: {
  'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
  '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
},
```

The `@` will be an alias to your `/src` directory. If you change this to reflect your current vue root, then you can migrate your app without a problem.