# Vuejs showing blank page after `npm run serve` and set up with IIS

Tags: vue.js, iis

[Error Message from blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejuby.png)

Not using History mode and still the same, tried a lot solution and yet it didn't sovle

I created a vuejs project with vue create my_project, after that I tried to run `npm run serve`, it showing me localhost:8081 and I tried to access it working. So after that i just `npm run build` and get the dist folder. I open up IIS and create Add Application > point the physical path to the dist folder then save it. When I run it showing blank and I try inspect in console, it showing me error message as I attached

Comment: Please provide us with more information about your setup. That error just means you are getting a 404 which could be caused by many things. Just double check that your traffic is being routed to index.html

Comment: How to check whether traffic is being routed to index.html?

Comment: Assuming you have used `npm run build` by just going to <server>/index.html should work. Also refer to this. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hosting-vue-js-spa-build-microsoft-iis-zainul-zain/

Without more information this is difficult

Comment: Also this helped me when deploying to azure https://stackoverflow.com/a/54649663/2073738

Comment: Let me try to provide more detailed information, this is my first time using stackoverflow.

So I created a vuejs project with vue create my_project, after that I tried to run `npm run serve', it showing me localhost:8081 and I tried to access it working. So after that i just 'npm run build' and get the dist folder. I open up IIS and create Add Application > point the physical path to the dist folder then save it. When I run it showing blank and I try inspect in console, it showing me error message as  I attached

Comment: Edit your question with that information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are many reasons for the error 404 failed to load resource. First you can check whether the file path is correct, and whether the iis account has permission to access the file.

Answer (score 0):

first you install `npm serve`

```
npm install serve -g
```

next, you need to write “serve” in the command window in the index.html file location

Comment: I did but still having the same issue